# how to print the decimal value to hex values in shell script

Tags: shell

I have a requirement of having a string which has a decimal value. For e.g., '0 2930 0'. Now , when i convert it to hex, it should say '0000 0B72 0000'. i'm able to convert  the values to hex using split and obase=16 with bc, i'll get the answer as '0 B72 0'. What i needed is to get the value '0000 0B72 0000'. Can anyone help shed some light on this?

Here is what i've done:

```
s1 ='2930'
echo after converting it to hexadecimal
s=`echo "obase=16; $s1" |bc`
echo $s
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `printf` for getting the output in the desired format:

```
$ printf "%04x " 0 2930 0
0000 0b72 0000
```

Comment: Thanks .. its working... But now, if i want to do the byte flipping in that... say the string is now '00000b720000' i wanted the output '0000 720b 0000'. Pls help me out

Comment: @user3202415 Could you please post a new question instead?

Answer (score 2):

Using bc as you have,

```
WANTED=456  ; echo "obase=16 ;$WANTED"|bc
```

and multiples

```
WANTED="{456 ;12 ;32000}"  ; echo "obase=16 ;$WANTED"|bc
```