# How to convert a column value in a file to its hexadecimal byte flipped format format

Tags: shell, sed, awk

Input file:

```
0 2950|abc|def|0|    
0 2564|abc|def|0|
```

Output file:

Append an additional `0000` after the conversion, i.e., i want the output as:

```
0000860B0000|abc|def|0|
0000040A0000|abc|def|0|
```

Only the first column is changed. I'm able to convert a value using print command. But how do I apply it to only the first column of the entire file of the above given input format
in shell scripting?

Ok i'm explaining the conversion process for first column,for example , 0 2950
, i've made hex of 0 i.e., 0000 and flipped it i.e again 0000 (00 00) and hex of 2950 (0B86)
and flip it 860B
(86 0B) and concat them i.e., 0000860B and since i want 12 byte word , i'll append the rest 0's i.e., 0000860B0000. Hope it clears everyone my requirement.

Comment: could the value be > `FFFF`? E.g `2F352` or even longer than 8 digits: `123456789`?  if yes, how would you do the "flipping"? or the value is just `7`, how would you flip it? `0700`?

Comment: Could you show how you "convert" and "print", it would make it much easier to help you.

Comment: @Thor I removed the text you added at the beginning of the question. because 1) it gave wrong info. OP wants to convert to HEX, and **flip**. your example doesn't have the flipping part. 2) the format of `$1` so far is not clear, it could be `FOO 1234`.   I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @Kent: As it stands it is hard to see how `0 2950` becomes `0000860B` without some further explanation. The text I added was from a [previously posed question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21161516/how-to-print-the-decimal-value-to-hex-values-in-shell-script) by the OP. Perhaps a modified version of that text would be better, one that includes the byte-swapping need? To your second point, based on the OPs previous question it seems that converted values always come in groups of 4 hex digits.

Comment: @Thor oh, I didn't notice that he asked question by question...

Comment: In the above output, the input decimal can take maximum value upto 5digits i.e., <FFFF, I want to convert as stated above

Answer (score 3):

as I commented, the requirement is not 100% clear, however for the example in your question (the value <= `FFFF`) this (gnu) awk line works:

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS="|" '{
sub(/^\S* */,"",$1);
$1=sprintf("%04X",$1);$1=gensub(/^(..)(..)$/, "\\2\\1","g",$1)}
$1="0000"$1"0000"' file
```

test one example:

```
kent$  cat f
0 2950|abc|def|0|
0 2564|abc|def|0|
0 7|abc|def|0|

kent$  awk -F'|' -v OFS="|" '{sub(/^\S* */,"",$1);$1=sprintf("%04X",$1);$1=gensub(/^(..)(..)$/, "\\2\\1","g",$1)}$1="0000"$1"0000"' f
0000860B0000|abc|def|0|
0000040A0000|abc|def|0|
000007000000|abc|def|0|
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 'y/|/ /;s/.*/printf "%04X%04X0000|%s|%s|%s|" &/e;s/(..)(..)/\2\1/2' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat file
0 2950|abc|def|0|
0 2564|abc|def|0|
0 7|abc|def|0|
```

Awk Code

```
awk '{
       gsub(/[[:space:]]/,x,$1)             # Remove Space in field1
       fmt=sprintf("%%0%dd%%s%%0%dd",4,4)   # Format variable for number zeros
       split(sprintf("%04X",$1),A,r)        # Split is used (if gensub not available as its feature of gawk)
       $1=sprintf(fmt,0,A[3]A[4]A[1]A[2],0) # Finally field1 with new values
     }1
    ' FS="|" OFS="|" file
```

Resulting

```
0000860B0000|abc|def|0|
0000040A0000|abc|def|0|  
000007000000|abc|def|0|
```

You may change `fmt` variable for number of zeros

Example : `fmt=sprintf("%%0%dd%%s%%0%dd",1,3)` 
Default it takes 1 zero on both side

Will result

```
0860B000|abc|def|0|
0040A000|abc|def|0|
00700000|abc|def|0|
```

If you want to try this on a `Solaris/SunOS` system, change `awk` to `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` , `/usr/xpg6/bin/awk` , or `nawk`